# What is the application of dimension $6$ representation of $SU(3)$ in particle physics?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

As we know, the $uds$ transforms in fundamental representations of $SU(3)$. It has the antifundamental partner. According to representation theory,
$$
\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{\bar{3}}= \mathbf{8} \oplus \mathbf{1} 
$$
where the $\mathbf{8} $ describes the mesons.

My question is if I am not taking $\mathbf{\bar{3}}$ to do tensor product but uses
$$
\mathbf{3} \otimes \mathbf{3}= \mathbf{6} \oplus \mathbf{3} 
$$
are there any physical fields transforming in $\mathbf{6}$? Any applications of it in particle physics?

Comment: The symmetric square of the natural rep would amount a combination of two quarks. IIRC there are no such elementary particles. A meson needs a quark and an antiquark, (anti)baryons three of either.

Comment: For QCD, gluons are made by one color (rgb) and one anti color (\bar{rgb}). Is there any theory in QCD describing the state with two color? Such as rr?

Comment: Search google for "color sextet". There are dozens of fanciful hypotheticals, none of them experimentally validated.